# display multiple checkbox in a single row of kendo UI Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working on Kendo UI. How to display multiple checkbox in a single row of Kendo UI Grid ?

Answer (score -1):

each Kendo component accepts a template which is in kendo's own format. You could setup that grid cell any way you want with as many checkboxes as you want.

have a look here for an example on how to do it : 
http://www.telerik.com/forums/checkboxes-in-kendo-grid

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Selection/select-multiple-rows-with-checkboxes

You might want to use telerik's forums for this kind of questions, they are very good at answering and you get replies from the people who actually created it.

Comment: I like to have multiple in a single row. because I have multiple roles for single user and I have to display check box for each role.

Comment: I like to have multiple checkboxes in a single row. because I have multiple roles for single user and I have to display check box for each rol

Comment: This should've been posted as a comment.